# Cannot rake migration for my ruby project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

When I try to rake a migration for my ruby project, it gives me an error "'API::sessions' is not a supported controller name". Does anyone know how to solve this problem? The following code is from my routes.rb file and sessions_controller.rb file.

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

get 'projects/:id', to: 'projects#show'
get 'projects', to: 'projects#index'

get 'welcome/index'
root 'welcome#index'
match '/login', to: 'sessions#new', via: :get
match '/login_create', to: 'sessions#create', via: :post
resources :users

scope :format => true, :constraints => { :format => 'json' } do
  post   "/api/login"       => "API::sessions#create"
  delete "/api/logout"      => "API::sessions#destroy"
end
end
```

---

```
class API::SessionsController < API::ApiController
skip_before_action :require_login, only: [:create], raise: false

def create
    if user = User.valid_login?(params[:email], params[:password])
        allow_token_to_be_used_only_once_for(user)
        send_auth_token_for_valid_login_of(user)
    else
        render_unauthorized("Error with your login or password")
    end
end

def destroy
    logout
    head :ok
end

private

def send_auth_token_for_valid_login_of(user)
    render json: { token: user.token }
end

def allow_token_to_be_used_only_once_for(user)
    user.regenerate_token
end

def logout
    current_user.invalidate_token
end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

The error appears when you define the `post` and `delete` routes within the `format` scope, to tell Rails which controller and action/method use for the URI being defined.

To refer then the controller name and action use the lowercase name followed by a slash, instead the uppercase controller name and colons `::`, like:

```
post   '/api/login'  => 'api/sessions#create'
delete '/api/logout' => 'api/sessions#destroy'
```